# Используют ли сейчас систему шаблонов Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Читаю книгу "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript" Робина Никсона. Там вкратце описана Smarty. Стоит самостоятельно углубиться, или сейчас применяют другие технологии в PHP для разделения кода и внешнего вида?

Учу PHP just4fun пока, что. В будущем планирую добавить его на борт известных мне технологий :).

Comment: В [моем вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/23630/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-vs-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) довольно много интересностей на эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите стать хорошим программистом, советую самому разрабатывать подобные системы, если же лишь для решения какой то задачи, не требующей уникальности, то смысл есть. Решайте)